# Merge Distinct Results, Assign Values in New Columns

Tags: sql

I have five columns in Table1. I need to create Table2 and combine those columns into one distinct values column ("Name"), create a new column ("Feature") based on the Table1 column name, and then assign an increasing # name ("Assigned_Name") based on that created column ("Features").

The three Comp columns in Table1 need to be identified as "Comp" in Table2.

**Table1 Columns:**

```
Product Region      Comp1   Comp2   Comp3
A       North       Legacy  New     Legacy
B       South       New     Old     Legacy
C       East        Old     Old     Legacy
D       West        Old     Legacy  Old
```

**Desired Outcome (Table 2):**

```
Name    Feature Assigned_Name
A       Product P1
B       Product P2
C       Product P3
D       Product P4
North   Region  R1
South   Region  R2
East    Region  R3
West    Region  R4
Legacy  Comp    C1
New     Comp    C2
Old     Comp    C3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `union all` should do what you want:

```
select product as name, 'product' as feature, 
       concat('P', row_number() over (order by product)) as assigned_name
from t
union all
select region, 'region', 
       concat('R', row_number() over (order by region))
from t
union all
select 'legacy', 'comp', 'C1'
union all
select 'new', 'comp', 'C2'
union all
select 'old', 'comp', 'C3';
```

You can read the unique values for the `comps` from the data using something like:

```
select comp, 'comp',
       concat('C', row_number() over (order by comp))
from ((select comp1 as comp from t) union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      (select comp2 as comp from t) union 
      (select comp3 from t)
     ) c
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way using union :

```
with cte as (
select Product name ,'Product' feature 
from table1 
union all
select Region name , 'Region' feature 
from table1
union all
select distinct comp1 name , 'comp' feature 
from table1
union 
select distinct comp2 name , 'comp' feature 
from table1
union 
select distinct comp3 name , 'comp' feature 
from table1
)

select *, row_number() over ( partition by feature order by feature) from cte
```